# Why pulsar pulses are so extremely regular?

Tags: exoplanet, pulsar

It's often said that the pulses of the pulsar have a very precise period, which helps to detect easily exoplanets that cause fluctuations in the time of arrival (TOA) of the pulses. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pulsars are precise because... in essence, there isn't much to cause them to be *imprecise*. It's as if you spun a top in intergalactic space and left it there for a hundred years - it would likely still be spinning (at pretty much the same rate).

In essence, pulsars are super-dense neutron stars that are rotating really fast, and their emission axis happens to line up correctly with Earth so that we see it as a pulsating source of radiation. Because there isn't really much to slow their rotation down, it stays relatively constant (though there can be what we call pulsar [glitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar)). However, pulsars do gradually "spin-down", and their period decreases over time (very slowly, mind you), and we can calculate this - we call it the p-dot, or period-derivative - the rate of change of the period, if you will. (As James K pointed out in his comment, this emission of radiation is also part of what causes this spin-down.)

Comment: The "why" is that the angular momentum can only be carried away by EM radiation from the spinning magnetic dipole, which, as you say, is slow.